# Git asks for password for each commit and pull

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github, bitbucket

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Git extension.
I am using bit-bucket for storing project.

Each and every time - whenever I want to either push or pull Git ask me for account password
in windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that the missing question is "How do I make it not do that?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [gitcredentials](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/gitcredentials.html) and tell it to remember your password for some time

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=time_in_seconds"
```

for example if you want it to remember for the next day it would be `60 * 60 * 24 = 86400` seconds, so the command would look like

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=86400"
```

Hope this helps.