# Git and Capistrano: Authentication failed for Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 (TFS)

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, capistrano3

Currently, I try to set up Capistrano 3 with my Rails project. But I have a problem with the Git settings.

I have to use Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 with Git support. The problem is that it only allows authentication using a HTTP request. There is no possibility to use a ssh key. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3801342-add-support-for-ssh-keys-as-alternate-authenticati

I do not want to store my password in ENV. How do I set up capistrano correctly to ask for the user and password?

For my old capistrano 2 config, I coded the complete steps my hand, because I had to use the old TFS without Git support.

By the way, I use Ubuntu for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and set a [credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309) like [git-credential-winstore](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) in order to cache your credentials.

you would enter your login/password once per session only.

The [OP Bjoernsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776481/bjoernsen) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693623/git-and-capistrano-authentication-failed-for-visual-studio-team-foundation-serv/23693698?noredirect=1#comment36409108_23693698):

> I am using Capistrano 3. I have found a solution.
>
> I asked our TFS admin to create a read only user account.
>   I added this user and its pw to my `.bashrc` and modified the git url.
>
> It works. It is not the best solution, but the fastest :-)

Comment: That worked with Git Extension (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19030243/6309), not sure it works with TFS using libgit2.

Comment: I tried to set up git with `git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600"`
The first time I cloned my Repo, git asked for the user and PW. The second time, it worked without user and password. But for 'bundle exec cap production deploy', it did not work. I still get `fatal: Authentication failed for ...`

Comment: @Bjoernsen is the bundle task executed with the same user account? A thread like this one (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/384) ends up using... ssh url (not possible here)

Comment: The thread you mentioned uses Capistrano 2. I am using Capistrano 3.

I have found a solution. I asked our TFS admin to create a read only user account. I added this user and its pw to my `.bashrc` and modified the git url. It works. It is not the best solution, but the fastest :-)

Comment: @Bjoernsen Ok. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.